# Magento 2.4.2: Data feed manager runs at a different time than at the one it is set to

Tags: magento2

We're using Wyomind data feed manager to pass product data to Google Merchant Center. The image below shows the settings for the data feed to be generated.

[image]

But the image below shows the actual time data feed was generated. I am not sure why this happened at 11PM instead of 7AM. The store is set to PST time.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cron is running always by UTC time.
so 7am - 8 (PST time ) = 11pm

Comment: Thank Kandy, but I didn't understand how your equation works. Could you please explain it a bit? I thought 8am PST is 4pm UTC not 11PM.